# Excel Transpose by Keeping Value Constant on Some of the column

Tags: excel, transpose

I have data in Excel as below:

H_ES003_FSA_DATA_REVIEWER   1193    1194    1195    1196    1197    1198

I like to convert it to format below by keeping constant value for column1, how do I do using formula ? or any other method in Excel 2010.

H_ES003_FSA_DATA_REVIEWER   1193
H_ES003_FSA_DATA_REVIEWER   1194
H_ES003_FSA_DATA_REVIEWER   1195
H_ES003_FSA_DATA_REVIEWER   1196
H_ES003_FSA_DATA_REVIEWER   1197
H_ES003_FSA_DATA_REVIEWER   1198

Comment: You can transpose (copy > paste special) the values you want to transpose, and just copy the constant down the other column.

Comment: I have too many rows to do manually so automatic formula preferred